# finite sum of cosines

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does any one have an idea how to find the following finite sum, for k and n integers and k < n?

$$
\frac{1}{k} \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \cos\left(\frac{2\pi n}{k}j\right)
$$

I tried the Lagrange trigoniometric identities but these doesn't seem to work always as for some n and k the denominator of the identity, $\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{k}\right)$, can be zero. Or do I miss something?

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

If $k$ divides $n$, then, for all $j$,
$$\cos\left(\frac{2\pi n}{k} j\right) = 1$$
so the sum is simply $(k-1)/k$.

Otherwise, note that 
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\exp\left(i\frac{2\pi n}{k} j\right) 
&= -1 + \sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\exp\left(i\frac{2\pi n}{k} j\right) \\
&= -1 + \frac{1 - \exp\left(i2\pi n\right)} {1 - \exp\left(i\frac{2\pi n}{k}\right)} \\
&= -1 + 0 = -1
\end{align}$$
Then
$$\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi n}{k}j\right) = \text{Re}\left( \sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\exp\left(i\frac{2\pi n}{k} j\right) \right) = \text{Re}(-1) = -1$$

Comment: Watch out for the case where $k$ divides $n$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Thanks, I always forget the darned $i$'s. And you're right, let me fix the case where $k$ divides $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: include $j=0$ and multiply by $k$, you have the sum of the real parts of the $n$'th powers of the $k$'th roots of unity.  There are two cases, depending on whether $k$ divides $n$.